# Redirect from image

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Всем привет!
У меня есть ссылка https://site.com/menuqr/menu.png
надо редиректнуть на https://site.com/menuqr/index.html

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

так и сделать

```
Redirect /menuqe/menu.png /menuqe/index.html
```

или

```
RewriteRule ^menuqr/menu.png menuqr/index.html  [L]
```

Comment: не знаю почему, но не работает почему-то так. Пробовал ((